# hub: Aborted: the origin remote doesn't point to a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

I committed some changes to a file and pushed it to GitHub:

```
git add myfile
git commit -m "some change to myfile"
git push origin feature
```

Then I would like to create a pull request:

```
$ hub pull-request -b master -h feature
Aborted: the origin remote doesn't point to a GitHub repository.
```

Since `origin` in the `git push origin feature` works, why does it say it doesn't point to a GitHub repository?

Also can I specify the reviewer and assignee from terminal?

Thanks.

---

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://git.xxx.net/xxx
  Push  URL: https://git.xxx.net/xxx
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    ...
```

Comment: origin's url could be anything. What is the url shown by ```git remote show origin```?

Comment: see my update. Why does `origin` in the `git push origin feature` works, but it doesn't point to a GitHub repository in `hub pull-request -b master -h feature`?

Answer (score 5):

This is mentioned in [the hub man page](https://hub.github.com/#work)

By default, hub will only work with repositories that have remotes which point to github.com. If you are using GitHub Enterprise, your host need to be whitelisted:

```
$ git config --global --add hub.host my.git.org
```

Answer (score 4):

`hub` is GitHub's command-line extensions available [here](https://github.com/github/hub).  It shouldn't be necessary for anything that is a core `git` feature.

Pull Requests, however, are a GitHub feature, not a `git` feature.  Your error message is entirely correct: "origin remote doesn't point to a GitHub repository" because `https://git.xxx.net/xxx` is not GitHub.

Options are:

- use GitHub, or
- don't use `hub`

Answer (score 0):

[Vincent Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4481170/vincent-zhang) has it right!

`$ git config --global --add hub.host git.xxxx.org`

(the `--global` is optional, of course)

Worked for me, it is in the man pages under `GitHub Enterprise`

https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Running `hub` on GitHub Actions, **in a different repo folder**, also got me the error `Aborted: the origin remote doesn't point to a GitHub repository`
In my case I had to use `hub pull-request --force` to make it work, since setting the remote didn't solve the issue.